# html select element bind using angularJS

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am working on web application. Is it possible to bind the select element on button click using AngularJS?

Here's my code:

```
<select name="hiatusWeeksSelect" ng-options="weeks.hiatusWeekDates for weeks in schedule.HiatusWeeks" size="11" multiple="multiple" style="width: 80px;margin-left:20px;margin-top:5px;"></select>
```

Comment: down vote..?comments pls

Comment: If you change the contents of `schedule.HiatusWeeks` on a button click it will already work

Comment: question is not understandable

Comment: You want to bind "Select" HTML on click right?

Comment: yeah..I want to bind this html select element on a button click.

Comment: `ng-show` or `ng-if` is not good enough? Your API returns the select html element instead of just the options data?

Answer (score 1):

Please check this http://plnkr.co/edit/2ja9TLKf4d7GDtYD7KGv?p=preview

Use ngSanitize

Download file - angular-sanitize.js and include it in your app.

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngSanitize"]);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.html = '';
    $scope.setHTML = function () {
      $scope.html ='<p class="text-color">Your html code</p>'; // You can have your HTML Select code here i.e
     //$scope.html ='<select name="hiatusWeeksSelect" ng-options="weeks.hiatusWeekDates for weeks in schedule.HiatusWeeks" size="11" multiple="multiple" style="width: 80px;margin-left:20px;margin-top:5px;"></select>';
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="myController">
    <span ng-click="setHTML()">Click Me</span>
    <p ng-bind-html="html"></p>
</body>
```